# Better implementation of "populist" badge

Tags: feature-request, badges, populist-badge

The populist badge is given when you have an answer that outscores an accepted answer with a score of 10 by more than 2x.

This creates a few perverse situations.  If there is an accepted answer with a score of 9 and someone else has an answer with a score of 99, they don't get the badge.  But if someone votes up the accepted answer then they do.

I suggest that populist should be like this

> When your answer outscores an accepted answer by more than **2x** and your score is **at least 20**.

It keeps to the original spirit of the badge, while avoiding the situation given above.

Comment: I think the badge was created with SO more in mind, where it's not unheard of that the accepted answer has vastly lower points than the highest voted answer. The "at least 10" points on the accepted answer seems cruel though.

Comment: This has annoyed me too. I have an answer which outscores the accepted one by more than 4x, but in order to get this badge, the _accepted_ answer needs two more votes. That feels kinda backward.

Comment: Especially if the accepted answer is flat-out wrong, gets tons of downvotes, but was accepted because the OP, to put it nicely, didn't know better. (Then again maybe there would've been enough downvotes on the question itself to earn the better answer a Reversal badge... *-shrug-*)

Comment: @hammar, which question? I'll upvote the accepted answer for you :-)

Comment: If the accepted answer didn't have a score of 10, wouldn't this basically overlap with the [Good Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/24/good-answer) badge?

Comment: @hammar, I went to upvote the relevant answer, but I see someone beat me to it.  Enjoy your badge :)

Comment: @Chris I don't see why badge overlap is a problem, lots of badges like great answer would require you to earn other badges along the way. The badges wouldn't be the same because this requires your high scoring answer to not be accepted, while a low scoring is--that's nothing like the good answer badge.

Answer (score 24):

Hmmm... It *sounds* reasonable on the surface. But it *does* change the context of the badge to some extent.

The original wording guarantees that the accepted answer was *highly* rated (i.e. a *good* answer with at least a score of 10). That may have been part of the *intention* of the badge. You are removing that *"I beat a **great** accepted answer"* criteria.

With the new wording, the populist badge can be awarded where the answer is not-so-great. It can have a score of zero or even negative… not quite the same *achievement*.

We'll have to look at the original *intention* of the badge so see if the new methodology would be preferred, or if it loses something important. I raised the issue with the developers for consideration.

Comment: This change would make it less like a Gold badge and more like a Silver.

Comment: I agree with you but why not use the badge terminology to classify the answer. For example (i.e. a nice answer with at least a score of 10)

Comment: Gold badges are like gold medals in the olympics. You don't get them without blood, sweat, and tears. Let's keep it that way. And I'm not just saying that cause I have a populist badge :)

Answer (score 5):

Badges are weird on the various smaller SE sites.  It's common for answers to get less than 10 votes, even when they're great answers.  So, good luck getting some of those badges on the other sites.

I have no idea if there's a way of 'tweaking' the numbers to make getting gold and silver badges as hard as it is on SO / SU, but not easier.

Comment: Very true.  Not many answers on UX.SE get more than 10 votes even when they are great answers.